# .htaccess mod_rewrite 1 RewriteRule for 3 cases

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

How do I write a single RewriteRule with Apache 2.4.16 (in XAMPP 5.6) to handle 3 possible cases? I have seen examples but they don't work.

After much struggle and reading, I finally got mod_rewrite to work with:

```
RewriteRule ^products/?$ /products.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$ /products.php?categoryname=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /products.php?categoryname=$1&productname=$2&productsku=$3 [NC,L]
```

3 lines isn't bad but I would like to improve this if possible. I tried some suggestions I found on the web but so far nothing else has worked. I assume it's because of older versions of Apache-- maybe?

Comment: In the test tool you linked to, the rules you have shown seem to work fine –`http://domain/products/category/product-name/product-sku` matches the first one, and `http://domain/products/category/` matches the second … so what’s the actual problem you”re having then?

Comment: Edited OP to explain problem better. Thanks CBroe

Comment: That RewriteCond doesn’t make sense – the following rule matches only if the request starts with `products/something` anyway, so preceding it with a RewriteCond that ensures the same thing is superfluous. If anything, the RewriteCond should make sure that the requested path is _not_ `/products/` _exactly_, so that you rules are not applied again in the next round, when you have already rewritten the request to `/products/`. (And a RewriteCond affects the following rule only, so if you want it to apply to the second rule as well, you have to repeat it before that rule.)

Comment: I think I understand what I need to do I just don't know the proper method/syntax to make it happen. I'm still not that great with RegEx so how, then, would I write my rules so they match only /products/category and another that matches only /products/category/product-name/sku?

Because `RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /products/?productcategory=$1&productname=$2&productsku=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$ /products/?productcategory=$1 [NC,L]`also causes 'internal server error' on everything that starts with `/products`

Comment: First of all, go check the server’s error log to find out what the actual cause of that internal server error is. It might have to do with that you are rewriting _to_ `/products/?…` – so `products` is an existing folder in your file system then? If so, try renaming it – or use a RewriteCond that checks if the REQUEST_URI does not match an existing folder before each rule.

Comment: This error is in there a LOT `[Sat Oct 17 16:21:57.582208 2015] [core:error] [pid 8956:tid 1836] [client ::1:62632] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I expected – so your rules are rewriting to `/products/?…`, and then on the next round that gets rewritten again … and again. Try implementing the RewriteCond that checks if the request URI is not an actual existing folder (assuming `products` is an actual folder?) – for details on how to do that, see the Apache documentation.

Comment: I thought the L flag was supposed to make it stop at that rule. I tried using RewriteCond to check if a folder exists and it works with one but gives me 'internal server error' if I use it with the second rule. This really seems like something a lot of websites have, or is my approach somehow fundamentally flawed? I did not find the Apache documentation helpful on this issue, which is kinda the whole reason I'm asking here.

Comment: The L flag stop evaluation of all following rules for the current round – but when rewriting is configured via htaccess, then after all rules are processed, it takes the new internally rewritten URL, and starts a second round, in which it goes through all the rules again – and that process is repeated, until no more rules match. // It often helps to enable rewrite logging, to see what is actually going on internally when a request comes in, what rules match and what it gets rewritten too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92668/discussion-between-sinrise-and-cbroe).